# Using PHP code and rename an image file before uploading to XAMPP database?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am new to php and is it possible to rename an image file before uploading to the database?

EDIT: would be using a form to upload the file to a database.

```
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Add" action="viewpage.php">
```

EDIT: IMAGE OF DATABASE:

[image]

---

[image]

The second image above still shows the original image file name in the database while the image name in the directory already changed.

Comment: dont store file in db, store it in the file system. store the name\location in the db

Comment: It will likely help if you include the code you are using on the upload

Answer (score 0):

**Yor can try this..**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
{
  $tmp_file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $rand = md5(uniqid().rand());
  $post_image = $rand.".".$ext;
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,"../post_imgs/".$post_image);
}
?>
```